# Чтение excel файла и запись его в бд

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, mysql

Добрый день! Использую фреймворк codeigniter. Есть файл newdisla.csv мне нужно открыть его и записать его в базу. я описываю действия в контроллере

```
public function upload_new_dislocation() //Загрузить новую дислокацию
{

    $this->load->helper('file');
    $handle = fopen("./upload/newdisla.csv", "r");       
         if(!$handle)
             {
                 echo 'Ошибка при открытии файла';
             }
         while(false !==($data = fgetcsv($handle))) 
            {
                $this->Unload_model->upload_disla();
            }
    $date_out = date("Y-m-d");
    $seldate = '$date_out';
    $res = $this->Unload_model->select_disla($seldate);
    while ($tablerows = $res)
    {

        $this->Unload_model->add();
    }
    fclose($handle);
    if (isset($res))
    {
        echo "Изменения внесены корректно";
        $this->index();    
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Произошел сбой! Обратитесь к админу!";
        $this->index(); 
    }
}
```

а в моделе строю запросы к базе

```
public function upload_disla()
    {
        $sql = array('id'=>'$data[0]',
                            'number_vagona'=>'$data[1]',
                            'naznachenie'=>'$data[2]',
                            'date'=>'$data[3]',
                            'time'=>'$data[4]',
                            'op'=>'$data[5]',
                            'operation'=>'$data[6]',
                            'dsd'=>'$data[7]',
                            'dpr'=>'$data[8]',
                            'index_poezd'=>'$data[9]',
                            'nomp'=>'$data[10]',
                            'gruz'=>'$data[11]',
                            'ves'=>'$data[12]',
                            'grpol'=>'$data[13]',
                            'disla_date'=>'$data[14]');
        $this->db->insert('newdisla', $sql);
         if(!$sql)
            {
                return false;
            }
    }

 public function select_disla($seldate)
    {

        $query= "select nd.*, vs.*
                 from newdisla nd
                 oin (
    select number_vagona, max(disla_date) maxdate
    from newdisla where disla_date <= '".$seldate."'
    group by number_vagona
    ) t on nd.number_vagona = t.number_vagona and nd.disla_date = t.maxdate
  join vagon_status vs on nd.number_vagona = vs.number_vagona
order by nd.naznachenie, nd.operation";
        $res = $this->db->query($query);
        if(!$res)
            {
                return false;
            }
       }
    public function add()
            {
    $sql = array('id'=>'$tablerows[0]',
        'number_vagona'=>'$tablerows[1]',
        'operation'=>'$tablerows[2]',
        'nahozdenie'=>'$tablerows[3]',
        'naznachenie'=>'$tablerows[4]');
        $this->db->insert('perevozki', $sql);
        if(!$sql)
            {
                return false;
            }
}
```

что я делаю не так, я не давно начала изучать СI(как и php).
За ранее спасибо!=)

Comment: т.е. у меня сейчас происходит чтение этого документа, проверяла var_dump($data) файл открывается и читается, проблема в передаче и записе в бд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А покажите код вставки полученных данный с файла в Базу?
 вот тут

```
 while(false !==($data = fgetcsv($handle))) 
        {
            $this->Unload_model->upload_disla();
        }
```

Вы считываете содержание файла в переменну дата - и больше с переменной $data  - ничего не происходит(
то есть поидее должно наверно быть так

```
while(false !==($data = fgetcsv($handle))) 
            {
                $this->Unload_model->upload_disla($data);
            }
```

и соответствено нада вам переписывать функции - точнее у всех указывать параметр который вы туда даете.Так как сейчас у вас все функции модели работают с переменными (полями) моделями.

В общем читайте про ООП в php, пользовательские функции

еще в функциях добовления и  обновления вы в массивах делаете следующее 'id'=>'$data[0]' и так далее со всеми полями - так вот по сути у вас в массиве ['id'] содержится строка $data[0], а вам нада загнать туда значение переменной - поэтому переписывайте вот так 'id'=>$data[0]

Comment: да я это исправила, но все равно не работает,)